# Angular + JSON: Retorno não aparece na tabela

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Olá, pessoal. Estou estudando e fazendo alguns testes em programação com PHP + AngularJS. Procurei em tudo quanto é lugar, mas não consegui de jeito nenhum imprimir em uma tabela html o array gerado pelo PHP.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Ficarei muito agradecido!

O código segue abaixo.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
                <td>{{detail.id}}</td>
                <td>{{detail.nome}}</td>
                <td>{{detail.email}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

**angular-script.js**

```
var App = angular.module('App',[]);

App.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope, $http){
    $http.post("usuarios.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.details = data;
    });
});
```

**usuarios.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "banco");

$query = "SELECT * from tab_usuarios";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {

    $i = 0;
    $arr = array('usuarios' => array());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $arr['usuarios'][$i]['id'] = utf8_encode($row['id']);
        $arr['usuarios'][$i]['nome'] = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
        $arr['usuarios'][$i]['email'] = utf8_encode($row['email']);
        $i++;            
    }            
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Quando executo usuarios.php, retorna o seguinte array:

```
    {"usuarios":[{"id":"1","nome":"Paulo Oliveira","email":"paulo@gmail.com"},{"id":"2","nome":"Olivia Pereira","email":"olivia@gmail.com"},{"id":"3","nome":"Lucio Costa","email":"lucio@gmail.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seja porque você está esquecendo de falar que quer o conteúdo dentro do array json, ficaria assim:

```
$http.post("usuarios.php").success(function(data){
  $scope.details = data.usuarios;
});
```

Até mais!

Comment: Fiz essa alteração, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Alguém mais pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Coloque um `console.log(data);` e tente ver pelo inspetor de página do seu navegador, tira uma print pra gente ver como está retornando.

Comment: Amigo, deu certo!

Comment: Tinha incluído a alteração que você havia postado no meu código original e não funcionou. Resolvi então implementar exatamente o trecho que escrevi aqui pro SO e, com a sua correção, funcionou. Vou verificar meu código inteiro, pois deve haver alguma _virgula_ fora do lugar.

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Só para registrar, com a correção que @victor_nascimento_j_gomes postou, o código funcionou perfeitamente.

Alterei:

```
$scope.details = data;
```

por:

```
$scope.details = data.usuarios;
```

Comment: Para registrar que a função dele deu certo, basta selecionar a resposta dele como "aceita" http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452/pergunta-j%C3%A1-tem-resposta-definida-por%C3%A9m-n%C3%A3o-foi-marcada-como-aceita?rq=1